# very strange issue with ng-selected and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I use AngularJS v1.2.3 and jQuery 1.7.1, the libraries are included in following sort order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

The following script works in a strange way, Firebug shows that item #2 has attribute "selected", but I see #1 as selected!

```
<select ng-app>
        <option value="1" ng-selected="3==1">#1</option>
        <option value="2" ng-selected="2==2">#2</option>
        <option value="3" ng-selected="1==3">#3</option>
</select>
```

When I change the sort order of scripts (angularjs before jquery), the code works as expected.

What do I must to do to prevent the issue? I can't change sort order of scripts

Update:
This is bug of jQuery 1.7.1:

```
// See #9699 for explanation of this approach (setting first, then removal)
jQuery.attr( elem, name, "" );
```

It was fixed later:

```
// Do not do this for boolean attributes (see #10870)
if ( !isBool ) {
  jQuery.attr( elem, name, "" );
}
```

Comment: What do you need jQuery for? Angular should have all the functionality you need.

Comment: use development version of angular not minified while in development, error output is more verbose. Please create demo in plunker that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Angular ships with a version of jqLite anyway so really you do not need to load an external jQuery anyway, unless you are adding angular to an already built solution.